# Make a variable keep caps lock letters

Tags: javascript

I have a variable in javascript that keep all the letters

```
 var letters=/^[a-z]+$/;
```

How to make this variable also keep the CapLock letters too... Thank you for helping me

Comment: Try `/^[a-z]+$/i` - the `i` is a flag for case insensitivity

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var letters=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
```

Comment: Yeah I'm kinda curious myself.

Comment: @user2804038 if this answer solved your issue please consider [**accepting it**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to indicate it solved your issue for future visitors, it also awards both you and him with extra site rep for playing nice with the system.